# How does "GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest" work?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've been researching how `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded` works. I want to know how it is able to participate in the compilation process to generate an embedded xml file.

Let me explain.

When I include the `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded` Nuget package into my project and add

```xml
 <PropertyGroup>
    .... (removed)
    <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>   
 </PropertyGroup>
```

to the project file, the compiled assembly contains a `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.xml` manifest resource.

However when I do not include this Nuget package but leave `GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest` in the project file, this xml file embedded resource is **not** generated.

Thus this Nuget package seems to participate in the compilation process and it seems to be able to read the project file and then generate an embedded resource using this information.

My question is to understand the mechanism in .NET that allows this to occur (since I want to replicate this behaviour).

I cannot see anything in the source code that does this.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/FileProviders/Embedded/src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is in here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/FileProviders/Manifest.MSBuildTask

Here's the code that creates the manifest XML file: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/FileProviders/Manifest.MSBuildTask/src/GenerateEmbeddedResourcesManifest.cs

And here's the target file that actually triggers that task: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/FileProviders/Embedded/src/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.targets

```
<GenerateEmbeddedResourcesManifest
      EmbeddedFiles="@(_FilesForManifest)"
      ManifestFile="$(_GeneratedManifestFile)" />
```